# How can I compute every possible tuple of lists from the elements V, V, V, M, M, M?

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

I have two lists, and six elements:

```
V V V M M M
```

I would like to compute every possible combination of those elements into two lists (left and right):

So, five possible solutions could be:

```
([V, V, V], [M, M, M])
([], [V, V, V, M, M, M])
([V, V, V, M, M, M], [])
([V, M, V], [V, M, M])
([V], [V, M, V, M, M])
```

My first approach was reducing the problem to that which had less elements (two). So, all possible solutions in that case are:

```
([], [V, M])
([], [M, V])
([V, M], [])
([M, V], [])
([V], [M])
([M], [V])
```

I can't seem to fit this problem into a basic standard combinatorics one, but perhaps there is something I am missing. How can I approach this problem ?

Comment: Are the bags distinct?  That is, if you put all the elements in one bag or the other, is that two different solutions or just one?

Comment: I note that in your example you appear to b e distinguishing between the ways to arrange the contents of each bag.  That's not typical for this sort of problem...which, of course, doesn't make it an illegitimate question, but it's the sort of thing that you ought to specify clearly.  If you have two distinct objects, $A,B$ and only one bag...are you saying the answer is $2$ because you can put either of the objects in first?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I think the issue is that the "objects in bags" vs "list of lists" analogy isn't great.  Lists are intrinsically ordered whereas objects in bags are not.  So, the question is "which of the two ways of looking at things did you intend?"

Comment: Thank you for your input, @lulu. I will think about your questions, and answer them.

Comment: >  if you put all the elements in one bag or the other, is that two different solutions or just one?
Yes, two different solutions @lulu. There is a left bag, and a right bag.

Comment: > I think the issue is that the "objects in bags" vs "list of lists" analogy isn't great. Lists are intrinsically ordered whereas objects in bags are not. So, the question is "which of the two ways of looking at things did you intend?"
Thank you, yes. I meant lists since order is important.

Comment: Ok, so then I suggest editing your post accordingly.  I think others will read the objects in bags part the same way I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unordered arrangement is specified by two numbers $n,m$ each between $0$ and $3$.  That is, we need to know how many $V's$ and how many $M's$ are in the lefthand list.

Now, given an unordered arrangement $(n,m)$ with $n$ $V's$ and $m$ $M's$ in the lefthand list, we need to order it.  The left hand list can be ordered in exactly $\binom {n+m}n$ ways since there are $n+m$ objects in total and we just need to place the $V's$ to specify the order.  At the same time, the right hand list has $(3-n,3-m)$ $V's, M's$ so there are $\binom {6-n-m}{3-n}$ ways to order it.  The total number of orderings of the state $(n,m)$ is then given by the product $\binom {n+m}n\times \binom {6-n-m}{3-n}$ and we need to sum over the possible states $(n,m)$.

Thus the answer is $$\sum_{0≤n,m≤3}\binom {n+m}n\times \binom {6-n-m}{3-n}=140$$

Computation supplied by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BBinomialCoefficient%5Bn%2Bm%2Cn%5D*BinomialCoefficient%5B6-n-m%2C3-n%5D%2C%7Bn%2C+0%2C+3%7D%2C+%7Bm%2C+0%2C3%7D%5D)

Note that this computation was "easy" because there are only two lists.  Specifying the contents of the first list also specified the second.   This would not be so easy if there were many lists.

Comment: Thank you so much for the through answer, @lulu. I tried with $n$, $m$ each between $0$ and $1$. However, the result is $52$, and my manual computation (the one I showed in my answer) is $6$. What do you think?

Comment: What do you mean? If gives $6$, of course.  Remember you have to change the threes into ones.

Comment: Sorry about that. This is the fixed computation: `Sum[BinomialCoefficient[n+m,n]*BinomialCoefficient[2-n-m,1-n],{n, 0, 1}, {m, 0,1}]`

Comment: Impressive. Thank you for your help.

Comment: How can I learn about this ? I would like to understand what's an unordered arrangement, and how did you come up for the left size and right size calculations.I have studied very basic combinatorics a long time ago, and it's not enough to fully understand your solution.

Comment: An unordered arrangement is as it sounds...that's the "objects in bags" version of the problem. In this case, all you need to do is to count the ordered pairs $(n,m)$ with $0≤n,m≤3$ and there are clearly $4\times 4=16$ such pairs.  That doesn't help much here, though, because the number of ways to order any such arrangement is not constant.  It depends on $n,m$.  That's why the problem gets  more difficult if you had many lists instead of just two.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to compute this number:

Suppose we have $n$ symbols, with $x_i$ occurences of the $i$th symbol, and denote the total number of symbols with repitions by $X$. And suppose we want to produce a list of $k$ lists.

First, order the list of symbols with repetitions arbitrarily, second, choose $m_1,...,m_k$, with $\sum_{i=1}^k m_i = X$, to be how many go in each list, and put the first $m_1$ symbols in the first list, the next $m_2$ symbols in the second list and so on.

Conversely given a list of lists as required we can recover the $m_i$s and the ordering of the list of symbols.

Now the number of ways to order the list of symbols is $\frac{X!}{\prod_{j=1}^{n} x_j!}$ (also knows as the multinomial coefficient), and for each such ordering we have $\binom{X+k-1}{k-1}$ ways to choose the $m_i$s (by the stars and bars method), so in total we have:
$$
\frac{X!}{\prod_{j=1}^{n} x_j!} \cdot \binom{X+k-1}{k-1}
$$
Such lists of lists.

In the case of $n=2$, $k=2$, this simplifies to
$$
\binom{x_1+x_2}{x_1}\cdot (x_1+x_2+1)
$$

for $x_1=x_2=1$ we get
$$
\binom{2}{1} \cdot 3=6
$$

and for $x_1=x_2=3$ (the original question):
$$
\binom{6}{3}\cdot 7=140
$$